# Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis with oracle

Tags: sql, node.js, oracle

While executing the below query getting this error but checked parenthesis are complete.

Error:  [Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis] {

```
 import oracledb from 'oracledb'
 const { ORACLE_USER, ORACLE_PASSWORD } = ORACLE_CONFIG

connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
  user: ORACLE_USER,
  password: ORACLE_PASSWORD,
  connectString: 'xxxx'
})
console.log('------------------*************[Info] Successfully connected to Oracle!************-----------------')

const { customerId, flag, Name, insertDate } = params
const result = await connection.execute(`Insert into table1
    (customer_id, name, status_flag, insert_date, update_date)
     Values
    (${customerId}, ${Name}, ${flag}, TO_DATE(${insertDate}, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE(${insertDate}, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))`)
```

Comment: share the full code

Comment: @dassum I think the issue is in the query

Comment: Do not use string literals for data values because of the security risks and performance implications.  Use bind variables as shown in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alessandro is right - you're using Template Strings, which just replace the template literal with your string. So with some example data, your insert statement at runtime actually looks like:

```
Insert into table1
(customer_id, name, status_flag, insert_date, update_date)
 Values
(111, Joe User, Y, TO_DATE(06/22/2020 16:07:00, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE(06/22/2020 16:07:00, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
```

Which is not valid SQL. You can put single quotes around your template strings like Alessandro suggests, and that'll fix it, but be aware that your code will be vulnerable to SQL injection.

The [node-oracledb docs have some examples of using bind variables](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/insert1.js), which are the best practice for SQL. For example, here's how to do it using "bind by position" syntax:

```
const result = await connection.execute(`Insert into table1
    (customer_id, name, status_flag, insert_date, update_date)
     Values
    (:customerId, :name, :flag, TO_DATE(:insertDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE(:insertDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))`, 
  [ customerId, flag, Name, insertDate, insertDate ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of strings without apostrophe on your code. Assuming that `${Name}`, `${flag}` and `${insertDate}` are strings, You need to put ' before  and after them, as you already have before and after `MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS`.

Comment: these are string literals which will be replaced by values at runtime

Comment: I know, but some languages doesn't pass the apostrophe of the variable for oracle, and I think Java is one of them because I work with a soft in Java and I have this exact same error when I pass variables without an explict apostrophe. Have you tried?